# Посчитать количество записей в базе

Tags: php, mysql

В базе есть поле `id_galery`, нужно его вывести в цикле и подсчитать его количество через GROUP BY id_galery.

```
$sql_count= "SELECT id_galery, COUNT(*) FROM images GROUP BY id_galery";
$res_count=mysqli_query($connection,$sql_count);
while($row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_count)){
echo $row_count['id_galery'].'<br />';
}
```

Этот зарпос выводит только `id_galery`, нужно, чтобы еще считало количество записей.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Так в запросе сделайте `... COUNT(*) AS galery_cnt ...`, а в PHP выводите как `$row_count['galery_cnt']`. Можно и в текущем виде (вроде как `$row_count['COUNT(*)']`), но через alias удобнее работать.

Comment: Спасибо, именно так и нужно было сделать. )